# cost of syscall very different on similar machines

Tags: linux, performance

I have two machines:

1) 2 x E5-2620 v3 @ 2.40GHz (microcode: 0x3c 2018-01-19), 8GB RAM (CentOS 7 w/ 4.11 kernel)

2) 2 x E5-2630 v3 @ 2.40GHz (microcode: 0x3c 2018-01-19), 64GB RAM (Fedora 22 w/ 4.11 kernel)

The kernels are custom compiled but otherwise without any modification. The `.config` for both builds are exactly the same (and neither have `kpti` since it was introduce on 4.14 iirc).

I wrote a code like:

```
beg = rdtsc_beg();
for (i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i)
{
    syscall(512); //ENOSYS
}
end = rdtsc_end();

printf("syscall: %lu cycles\n", (end - beg) / 1000000);
```

to measure the cost of a syscall. I get 99 cycles on machine 1 and 264 cycles on machine 2.

I can not understand why there is such a huge difference given almost anything *that I think is relevant* being the same.

Any ideas what might be causing the difference or any clue where I should be looking to find out the cause?

Edit:

I changed the code to:

```
volatile int ret = 0;

beg = rdtsc_beg();
for (i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i)
{
    ret++;
}
end = rdtsc_end();

printf("inc: %lu cycles\n", (end - beg) / 1000000);
```

And compiled statically:

```
400a3f:       0f a2                   cpuid
400a41:       0f 31                   rdtsc
400a43:       89 d6                   mov    %edx,%esi
400a45:       89 c7                   mov    %eax,%edi
400a47:       48 c1 e6 20             shl    $0x20,%rsi
400a4b:       89 ff                   mov    %edi,%edi
400a4d:       b8 80 96 98 00          mov    $0xf4240,%eax
400a52:       48 09 fe                or     %rdi,%rsi
400a55:       0f 1f 00                nopl   (%rax)
400a58:       8b 54 24 0c             mov    0xc(%rsp),%edx
400a5c:       83 c2 01                add    $0x1,%edx
400a5f:       48 83 e8 01             sub    $0x1,%rax
400a63:       89 54 24 0c             mov    %edx,0xc(%rsp)
400a67:       75 ef                   jne    400a58 <main+0x28>
400a69:       0f 01 f9                rdtscp
400a6c:       41 89 d0                mov    %edx,%r8d
400a6f:       89 c7                   mov    %eax,%edi
400a71:       0f a2                   cpuid
```

The result is 5 cycles on Machine 1 vs 14 cycles in Machine 2.

Comment: I'm guessing it is a power setting in the BIOS or OS.

Comment: @MarkWagner I passed `intel_idle.max_cstate=0` as boot param to kernels to no avail. I will look into BIOS power settings. Thanks.

Comment: Are the versions of the compiler and glibc identical?

Comment: @duskwuff I used the same static binary of the code above on both machines. So, yes for the benchmark.

The kernels are built with different gcc versions.

Comment: @MarkWagner sounds like a power/freq scaling issue. The frequency on Machine 1 maxes at 3.2GHz but Machine 2 is throttled at 2.6GHz for the same workload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> sounds like a power/freq scaling issue. The frequency on Machine 1 maxes at 3.2GHz but Machine 2 is throttled at 2.6GHz for the same workload.

Force them to use the same power settings. In addition to checking BIOS, install `tuned` on both and set the profile to `latency-performance`

---

Get a second opinion on the cycles by running your binary with `perf stat`.

Comment: Turned out the issue was from the BIOS configuration.